# Rescue from routing error rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

How to rescue from `RoutingError` in rails 3.1 application. If i'm nt mistaken it was possible to use `rescue_from RoutingError` in application controller but now it's not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no great way to handle it, but there are a few workarounds.  The discussion [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/671) yields the following suggestion:

**Routes**

Add the following to your routes file:

`match "*", :to => "home#routing_error"`

and handle the error in this action:

```
def routing_error
  render text: "Not found, sorry", status: :not_found
end
```

Comment: The more technically correct response would be `render text: "Not found, sorry", status: :not_found, content_type: Mime::HTML` to correctly handle responses like `/icon.png`

Comment: Infact, the solution from @aboutaaron worked for me. Just a "*" in the route-pattern didn't work. Needed to add some CRAP :)

Answer (score 7):

I wasn't able to replicate @matthew-savage's results. However, per the Rails guide on [route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12926332/868724) on another StackOverflow question, I solved this issue like so:

routes.rb

```
match "*gibberish", :to => "home#routing_error"
```

notice how I included text after the wildcard. The controller is fine as shown above:

controller/home_controller.rb

```
....
def routing_error
    render text: "Not found, sorry", status: :not_found
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Good [example](https://gist.github.com/Sujimichi/2349565).

**route.rb**

- Rails 3:

  `match '*unmatched_route', :to => 'application#raise_not_found!'`
- Rails 4:

  `get '*unmatched_route' => 'application#raise_not_found!'`

**application_controller.rb**

```
def raise_not_found!
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new("No route matches #{params[:unmatched_route]}")
end
```