# Error using wildcards and redirect on routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
match "/myroute*" => redirect("http://google.com"), :as => :myroute
```

The line above in `routes.rb` is causing the following error

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/racc/parser.rb:349:in `on_error':      (Racc::ParseError)
parse error on value ")" (RPAREN)
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/racc/parser.rb:99:in `_racc_do_parse_c'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/racc/parser.rb:99:in `do_parse'
```

Looks like it is because I'm adding a wildcard (*). Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wildcard components need to have a "label" as well, e.g.

```
match "/myroute*something" => redirect("http://google.com"), :as => :myroute
```

will match `/myrouteblah` and `/myroute/hello/world` where `params[:something]` is `blah` and `/hello/world` respectively.

EDIT: Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/routing.html#route-globbing if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
match ':redirect' => redirect("http://google.com"), :as => :myroute , :constraints => { :redirect => /myroute.?/i }
```